# Amazon WorkSpace Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have few queries related to Amazon Workspace.
Q1) I am building a .net website from where I want to access the Amazon Workspace. What could be a better way to do so? Is it possible that I create a webpage in my website and from there I can access the Workspace desktop in an iFrame or something? or is there any API support for same?

Q2) Can we set some startup program in Amazon Workspace which initiates any application for eg: photoshop, whenever the Workspace is started?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the point of Amazon Workspaces - they are a virtual desktop solution (loosely similar to Citrix), which provides a Windows 7 or Windows 10 'Desktop Experience' running on top of Microsoft Windows Server 2008 and 2012 respectively.

So, to answer your questions:

> Q1) I am building a .net website from where I want to access the
>   Amazon Workspace. What could be a better way to do so? Is it possible
>   that I create a webpage in my website and from there I can access the
>   Workspace desktop in an iFrame or something? or is there any API
>   support for same?

*You don't want to embed a Workspace instance inside of a web-page*, either as an iFrame or by using some other magic. It is probably possible, but you will need to jump through many, many burning hoops of death to achieve it.

If you want to access a web-page that you are building from the Workspace instance, treat Workspaces as just any other desktop and use Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, Opera etc. to access the site.

If you are looking at how to access Workspace Instances, AWS have desktop clients for all major Operating Systems, as web-based version (not to be confused with the web-page that you personally are writing); alternatively, Workspaces can be accessed from physical PCoIP Zero-Client devices. Take a look at https://clients.amazonworkspaces.com/ for the full list.

> Q2) Can we set some startup program in Amazon Workspace which
>   initiates any application for eg: photoshop, whenever the Workspace is
>   started?

Yes you can, configure a Group Policy Object in your underlying Workspaces Directory to start an application on logon.

However, if you are going to run something intensive such as Photoshop, I would recommend either the Performance or Graphics Bundles - see https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/details/ for more information.